Transferring to a new iPhone it asks for the password to an AppleID that does not belong to me
I just got a new iPhone and proceeded to transfer everything to the new iPhone using Apple's transfer procedure.
Partway through the transfer when it was downloading my apps it asked for the password from an AppleID that likely belonged to the boss at a company I worked at a decade or more ago.
I seem to recall this happening the last time I got a new phone and cancelling the password request solved that particular issue and allowed the iPhone to continue with setup.
How can I find what exactly the app was that generated the password request? It wasn't indicated what app needed authorization when asking for the password. It is mostly just strange and mildly annoying (once!) as it never prompts for a password again.
I have no way of getting in touch with the former boss and have been through my list of apps "purchased" and recognize nothing that could even remotely be associated with that company.
Any idea how to run down what app is doing this and deleting it from my account?

You can see a list of the apps you installed under your own Apple Account (as it's now called) in the account information in the App Store. Any app that's installed but not on that list is from somebody else.

The problem is that it is not installed because installing it requires authentication from an account I only vaguely recognize because of the name that it contains. Any apps "not on this iPhone" are not old enough to be an app over a decade old.

Then it’s not clear that you still have a problem. If you do, what is it?

The issue occurs during migration. When the new iPhone asks for the password from a foreign account. Tapping on "cancel" allows the migration to proceed. I'm just trying to discover if there is a way to identify what app is causing this behavior.

The migration is done. If you’re just curious as to which app on the old phone caused the prompt, you can do what I suggested on that phone, unless it’s been erased. Otherwise I’m still missing something.

There is no app listed on my iPhone (App Store > Account > Apps > My Apps) that could possibly be the app in question. I'm not just curious, I am annoyed by a recurring issue that happens every time I switch to a new phone. So your "answer" does not come close to solving the issue, as the list of apps installed (or not on this phone) does not contain a possible candidate app.

What I wrote in the answer is that the App Store only lists apps that were purchased using your Apple Account. If you're being prompted for the password of a different account, that means an app was installed using that account, not yours, and therefore will not be in the list of purchased apps under your account. You have to find the app that is on the phone but not on that list. If that doesn't solve the problem, then I don't know how to solve it.

One other point that might cause confusion. Depending on how the data is migrated (or maybe always, I'm not sure), apps are not fully installed from existing copies. An empty placeholder is put in their place, and the apps are downloaded from the App Store. That might be what is happening to you. So you would be looking for the icon of an app that isn't fully installed.

Unfortunately there is no placeholder app. Nothing I don't recognize. I was hoping that someone knows how to plumb the depths of a log somewhere that would indicate what this app is. I appreciate your sticking with this but so far my years troubleshooting Macs and PCs are all for naught on this particular issue...

If I had some unknown crap on my phone, I'd erase it and set it up as new. Data migration doesn't really save that much time, maybe an hour or two to reinstall your apps and recreate the settings. You don't lose any content if you sync it all with iCloud. Worth it for the peace of mind.

The problem is is interrupts/stops the migration. If I can’t provide a password for the app it doesn’t install so it is an annoyance/interruption to the migration process that I would like to get rid of.

I don't have anything useful to add, because I still don't understand what the problem is. We seem to be assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that some app was installed on your old phone using someone else's Apple Account. During migration to your new phone, you were prompted for the password of that account, which you don't have. The migration proceeded without it, and the app was omitted. Next time you migrate to a new phone, there should be no problem. But you seem to feel otherwise. I don't understand why. I also don't know why you can't search the old phone for the problem app.

There is no "foreign" app on my phone. As far as I can tell nothing was installed as I canceled the password prompt for the account that owned the app. The problem is that during migration to the new phone it stops and waits for the password for that app. This has been going on for years. I would just like to find what app is asking for a password I never had access to and remove any reference to it so it stops interrupting migration.

Why do you think an app is causing the prompts? What do they say, exactly?

Something like "to install this you must provide the password: johnny@appleseed.org) I don't remember the specific wording but it refers to an app belonging to a specific AppleID with a name in it from well over a decade ago (former boss). It does reference an app but does not name it. It also happened on my wife's new iPhone and for an app she uses via family sharing that I bought. Same dialog box that doesn't mention which app.

Are we now talking about two different apps on your wife's phone, one of which you bought in your own account?

As an example, yes. It asked for the unknown app password, which I just cancelled as usual. Then my AppleID password for the couple of apps that she has on her iPhone via family sharing. Neither prompt indicates which app is prompting for a password. Which would be helpful, Apple...

What happens if you disable Family Sharing? I'm starting to think you somehow included your boss in it, or he included you.

Hmmmmm, worth a shot next new phone, thx
